# Chaining rows in a SQL Server table in a distributed system

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, race-condition

Let's say that I have the following SQL table where each value has a reference to the previous one:

ChainedTable

```
+------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+
| SequentialNumber | GUID                                 | CustomData | LastGUID                             |
+------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+
|                1 | 792c9583-12a1-4c95-93a4-3206855d284f | OtherData1 |                                    0 |
+------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+
|                2 | 1022ffd3-afda-4e20-9d45-eec884bc2a50 | OtherData2 | 792c9583-12a1-4c95-93a4-3206855d284f |
+------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+
|                3 | 83729ad4-2564-4146-b451-00d82585bd96 | OtherData3 | 1022ffd3-afda-4e20-9d45-eec884bc2a50 |
+------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+
|                4 | d7197e87-d7d6-4175-8172-12656043a69d | OtherData4 | 83729ad4-2564-4146-b451-00d82585bd96 |
+------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+
|                5 | c1d3d751-ef34-4079-a73c-8952f93d17db | OtherData5 | d7197e87-d7d6-4175-8172-12656043a69d |
+------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+
```

If I were to insert the sixth row, I would retrieve the data of the last row using a query like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 (SequentialNumber, GUID) FROM ChainedTable ORDER BY SequentialNumber DESC;
```

After that selection and before the insertion of the next row, an operation outside the database will take place.

That would suffice if it is ensured that only one entity is using the table every time. However, if more entities can do this same operation, there is a risk of a race condition. There is the possibility that one entity requests the information of the last row and before doing the insert on the second one.

At first, I thought of creating a new table with a value that indicates if the table is being used or not (the value can be null or the identifier of the process that has access to the table). In that solution, the entity won't start the request of the last operation if the value indicates that the table is being used by another process. However, one of the things that can happen in this scenario is that the process using the table can die without releasing the table, blocking the whole system.

I'm sure this is a "typical" computer science problem and that there are well known solutions to implement this. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Just search on the term [sql race condition](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+race+condition&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS727US727&oq=sql+race+condition&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0i20i263j0i22i30l7j0i10i22i30.3729j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). And when a process dies (along with its connections to the database), any locks will automatically be released. That is a situation that you should anticipate and handle and test, but it should be rare.

Comment: I don't understand: why are you selecting out the `SequentialNumber` at all? Just let the server increment the next ID (which it is perfectly capable of doing safely). Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: To echo @Charlieface, why not use either an identity column or column whose default is `next value for dbo.SomeSequence`?

Answer (score 0):

I think using Transaction in SQL may solve the problem For example, if you create a transaction that will add a new row, no one else will be able to do the same transaction until the first one is completed.